# Standard category fields for all cat groups?

Tags: categories

I do not see a way yet to do this within EE. But would be a huge time consumer not to mention pain on the front end to manage different custom field names that I want to display using the same field name across multiple category groups.

I could manually create the field for each group with the id of the group appended or something and just swap it in but still that would be a lot of extra work for when all I want a set of custom fields for all category groups similar to how I can use the same channel fields group between multiple channels.

Any ideas of a way to handle this without manually creating custom fields for each group would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The only solution I can see here is to use *channels* as opposed to *categories* to handle your taxonomies, then using [Playa](http://pixelandtonic.com/playa) to associate your actual channel entries with your "categories". This way you can actually use channel field groups for your category data.

But you do lose the easy setup of EE's dynamic URLs to filter by category in this case, instead requiring a mixture of Playa `entries`, `parents` and `children` tags, alongside the Channel module's `entries` tag.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately that is not going to work because I am dealing with an existing site that handles most of the site layout based on the category lists. Ugh. I think what I may do is create a new channel just for fields and have a field that is a cat select and then any additional text fields that I need and then just do a query on the front to pull in these custom fields from that channel if active cat equals the cat selected. So similar to what you suggested. I'm suprised there is not another option for this though.

Comment: Ah, I see. In my experience, different category groups have differing field needs, so this might be a rare use-case (hence it not being implemented, via add-on or in core).

Comment: depending on how many categories you have, instead of storing the meta data in a channel, you could store it in low-variables or "misuse" the category description to hold some data (generated html by a custom add-on, or some json, maybe an id etc.)